# Lint - how to suppress warnings about unresolved variables

Tags: node.js, lint

Node.js linter is warning about a lot of unresolved variables in cases where properties are dynamically set, like on req.params.

Is there some lint syntax I can use to ignore or suppress those warnings?

Thank you.

Comment: Node.js does not have a linter. Your project probably uses [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) or [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) for linting. Each of them has its own rules and directives.

Comment: Yes eslint.- thanks for any advice

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

put on the line above your code next comment line"

```
// noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
```

works for me well
for instance:

```
// noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
your code with variable
```